# Regarding the Rank-Nullity theorem: Is a linear mapping $\Phi:V\rightarrow W$ that satisfies $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$ injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, machine-learning

For a given linear mapping $\Phi:V\rightarrow W$, where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces, the rank-nullity theorem states that $\dim(\ker(\Phi))+\dim(\mathrm{Im}(\Phi))=\dim(V).$ A textbook that I'm studying (Mathematics for Machine Learning by Deisenroth et al.) makes the following claim (p. 60):

> If $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$, then $\Phi$ is bijective (since $\mathrm{Im}(\Phi)\subseteq W$).

This doesn't seem to be correct though because if $\Phi$ is bijective, then it's injective (one-to-one). Injectivity of $\Phi$ implies that *only one element* in $V$ can map to $\mathbf{0_W}$ in $W$. Consequently, $\ker(\Phi)$ would need to be trivial (only contain $\mathbf{0_V}$). The condition that $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$ doesn't seem to imply that $\ker(\Phi)$ is trivial.

**My question is:** Should this condition be $\dim(V)=\dim(\mathrm{Im}(\Phi))$ instead of $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$?

Thank you in advance!

(As a side note, MML has been a delight to learn from so far!)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct. $\Phi$ could be, stupidly, the zero map. Then what?

Comment: The version of this claim that is correct is that, if you assume $\Phi : V \to W$ is injective **or** surjective, where $\dim V = \dim W$, then $\Phi$ is bijective. Ted points out an easy example where injectivity, surjectivity, and hence bijectivity fail to hold (so long as $V$ and $W$ are non-trivial).